# Is web check-in mandatory in German Wings?

Tags: air-travel

I got a message from a Germanwings partner (where I bought the ticket) informing I can do my on-line check in.

I tried but I can't complete the process without choosing a sit and paying extra.

Is online check in mandatory? Would I pay extra to make the check in at the airport?

I didn't find usefull information at their website. It was not clear.

Comment: Do check carefully if you can find a “no thanks” button or similar somewhere on the website. Nowadays, with low cost carriers, it's often “hidden” to push for extra services but typically it's still there somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

The FAQ has a [whole section on regular (non-web) check-in](https://www.germanwings.com/en/Service/FAQ_Check_In.htm) and mentions “check-in desk” without hinting at extra costs so it seems pretty safe to conclude that checking in at the airport is possible (I have not done it myself).

Also, [Can I choose my seat when I check in?](https://www.germanwings.com/en/Service/FAQ_Check_In_Can_I_choose_my_seat_when_I_check_in.htm) implies that choosing a seat should not cost you anything:

> You can check in and reserve a seat free of charge by checking in online or using a check-in kiosk at the airport.

(Selecting an exit row with extra leg room does cost extra.)

Answer (score 1):

I flew with Germanwings last year and checked in at the airport on both legs. No extra charge.